# Getting the value from function in an imported class for a progress bar (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, oop

This should be an easy one, but I don't know the terms to google it effectively

I have my Main.py which imports class GetPointDistance from the getPointDistance.py file.

The main.py can send variable to the GetPointDistance, but how can I set it up so the variable (called in Main) gets updated, I really want to use this for a progressbar, but lets just sat I want to return the value of x which is on a for loop in getPointDistance and have the print function in Main.

For instance:

(Main.py)

```
import getPointDistance

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('pyqtdesigner.ui', self)
    ...
    ...
    def near_dist_top(self):
        getPointDistance.GetPointDistance.calculate_nearest_top(self, distance)
        print(value_from_getPointDistance)
```

(getPointDistance.py)

```
class GetPointDistance:
    def calculate_nearest_top(self):
        top_dist_list = []
        for i in range(len(T)):
            print(i)
            return i
```

I want to return a value from getPointDistance (i) and access it in Main

Comment: You're mixing up things. `calculate_nearest_top` is instance method, you need an instance to call it like `gpd = GetPointDistance(); gpd.calculate_nearest_top()`. If you want to pass a value to it you need to declare as `def calculate_nearest_top(self, argument)`. It seems that you don need a class for calculate_nearest_top`, since you dont use self in the body of the method, a simple function would suffice

Comment: In this case you can get rid of `GetPointDistance` class and call it directly in `near_dist_top`, `value = getPointDistance.calculate_nearest_top(); print(value)`

Comment: I over simplified things/poor example, I'll add some of the real code.